# vsftpd behind Router (passive mode) not working properly

Tags: networking, router, ftp, ssl

I am currently running a vsftpd server behind a router. But unfortunately it is not working properly, I can connect, I see the files and sometimes I can download and upload but sometimes it just says 100% in the client and then it times out.

vsftpd.log says: *Connection terminated without SSL shutdown - buggy client?*

FileZilla says, when I want to connect: *Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.*

So I did some research but tried some stuff, but it didn't actually work. So my current vsftpd.conf looks like this:

```
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
require_ssl_reuse=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH


listen_port=646

pasv_enable=YES
pasv_addr_resolve=YES
pasv_min_port=50000
pasv_max_port=55000
pasv_address=*.*.eu
```

I tried it with my dyndns address or I also just tried it with my public address. No change!

What could still be the problem?

Thanks!!

Comment: What version of FileZilla and vsftpd?

Comment: the newest FileZilla 3.18, 3.0.2 vsftpd